# Matlab pointy line connections

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plot with LineWidth=2 similar to

```
plot([0 1 2 10],[0 10 0 0],'LineWidth', 2)
```

Is there some way to make the line connections (as in the point (1,10)) less pointy without adding extra points to the plot? E.g. a "curved" line connection would be better.

Comment: To clarify: What I meant was that the line in pointy connections extends very far from the point, compare e.g.
    plot([0 1 2 10],[0 10 0 0],'LineWidth', 2) with
    plot([0 1 1 2 10],[0 10 10 0 0],'LineWidth', 2), which looks better. I still want the lines to be straight.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab R2015 you can use the [Curve Fitting App](http://es.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/interactive-curve-and-surface-fitting-.html).

First define your `x` and `y` variables:

```
x = [0 1 2 10];
y = [0 10 0 0]
```

Then open the app by clicking on the `APPS` tab and then `Curve fitting`. The app will open in a new window. In it,

- You select your variables in the `X data` and `Y data` drop menus; and then
- Choose parameters for the fitting (the two drop-down menus on the upper right part).
- You can also click in the `Legend` button to remove or include a legend.

See the figure below, in which I selected `Interpolant` model and the `Shape-preserving (PCHIP)` method.

[image]

Lastly, if you click on the `File` menu and then `Print to Figure` you get an independent figure with the plot, as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, thats a nice tool, but it doesn't really solve the problem. Maybe I didn't explain the problem clear enough; what I meant was that the line in pointy connections extends very far from the point, compare e.g.
    plot([0 1 2 10],[0 10 0 0],'LineWidth', 2)
and
    plot([0 1 1 2 10],[0 10 10 0 0],'LineWidth', 2). I still want the lines to be straight.

Comment: Oh, I see. That wasn't clear at all in your original question. One workaround would be to automatically repeat each `x` and `y` value (as you have done with the peak). I mean instead of `plot(x,y)` use something like `plot(kron(x, [1 1]), kron(y, [1 1]))`. But there should be a more elegant way